# react native linking a library to inside the another library

Tags: react-native, react-native-linking

Is it possible to link a library which has native dependencies inside another library? Trying to find the solution to link manually, but failing to do it so. I found a [question]: [Using React-Native library inside another React-Native library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54219544/using-react-native-library-inside-another-react-native-library) summary, saying It is not possible to add/link a library to another library.
Is there any manual way to do this or not possible?

**[Edit]**

Trying to add the `react-native-spring-scrollview: ^2.0.20` library to my library `react-native-demolibrary`, which is a library created using `react-native-create-library` command, since it is a library there were no `settings.gradle` file. So created and tried to link manually library to `react-native-somelibrary`.

> settings.gradle

```
include ':react-native-spring-scrollview'
project(':react-native-spring-scrollview').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-spring-scrollview/android')
```

> build.gradle

```
implementation project(':react-native-spring-scrollview')
```

below error has shown up,

> GRADLE CONSOLE ERROR

```
org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Build file 'E:\Workspace\DemoApp\node_modules\react-native-demolibrary\android\build.gradle' line: 37
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-library'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:139)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getConfiguredBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:104)
    at .....more
```

> ERROR:

```
Project with path ':react-native-spring-scrollview' could not be found in project ':react-native-demolibrary'.
    Open File
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps try including what you're trying to link, why it's not working and what you the outcome should be if it were successful. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: @swonder I have tried to link react-native-spring-scrollview using `react-native link react-native-spring-scrollview` and I've linked it manually, facing the same error.